# Undergraduate quantum book treating density operators, mixed states, and entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

I'm working on a project on quantum measurement theory - in particular, relating to the quantum Zeno effect - over the summer. Right now, I'm in the process of doing background readings that'd enable me to tackle the problem in a few weeks.

I'm looking for a resource recommendation for a QM textbook (for self-study, of course) that deals with the ideas of density operators, mixed states, entangled states, Bell's Inequality, CHSH and other topics that may fall in this category. Most of the undergraduate textbooks I have read thus far (mainly Shankar, Townsend and Beck) don't include these topics.

I'd appreciate if someone could recommend related textbooks on this front, ideally suited for a third year undergraduate who has done standard undergraduate QM sequence.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I made some edits to this question. Please note that in English we only capitalize [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) and the first word of a sentence. Also, please do read our [FAQ on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: I can't think of any books that go over CHSH, but Griffiths does cover Bell inequalities a bit. For density matrices and that sort of thing it's a bit harder because most of the usual quantum books just barely talk about it. You might want to try a quantum information book instead.

Comment: About density matrices I can recommend L. D. Faddeev, O. A. Yakubovskii, Lectures on Quantum Mechanics for Mathematics Students.

Comment: No one here nor in the linked question has yet mentioned Quantum Processes, Systems and Information by Benjamin Schumacher and Michael Westmoreland. It is an introductory quantum mechanics and quantum information textbook. Density operators, entanglement, CHSH inequalities, CP maps, open system dynamics; everything is there.

Answer (score 2):

A book that I highly recommend which covers the said topics is "Lectures on Quantum Theory: Mathematical and Structural Foundations" by Chris Isham. His treatment is more thorough than most textbooks and has some interesting insights. It is also well suited for someone without a deep quantum background.

Two books which also covers these topics and are quite nice are "Modern Quantum Mechanics" by JJ Sakurai and "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by Steven Weinberg. These are not undergraduate quantum books but are extremely well written and should be readable for someone with your background.